# Design pattern and help class to merge properties as in the PropertyGrid control

Tags: c#, properties, propertygrid

I'm not sure how this is called and maybe it is already answered somewhere else. Basically I have classes containing properties and than I have custom GUI controls to modify them.

I would like to achieve something similar to what you can find in the `PropertyGrid` control: if two objects of the same class are selected, then their properties are merged; equal properties are displayed and not equal are not; a change  to a property is reverberated to all the underlying selected objects.

Somebody can tell about a design pattern for this or even maybe help classes to manage this? Comprehensive details or examples would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to use for that PropertyProxy DesignPattern

Comment: Can you please provide links to resources?

Comment: i can recomand you great course of design patterns at .Net - https://www.udemy.com/design-patterns-csharp-dotnet/learn/v4/content